How to have runtime visualization of code symbols
Is there a way to generate a graph view of a run, similar to stacktrace but just have it as a graph view.
Stack traces could be visualized as graphs by having the file source as the node and then arrows pointing outwards to other files.
No labels on the arrows yet just something that visualizes a code run.
Tree-sitter, but this is not runtime specific, doesn't reveal how the flow of a values and logic occurs.
The next-best thing would just be a debugger
